# Access query formula to calculate date of previous Tuesday

Tags: ms-access

Not sure where to start. I have a Delivery Date for which I need to acquire the date of the previous Tuesday (unless the date is a Tuesday, in which case I use that date). I am doing this as a formula in an Access query, not vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `Weekday(DelDate,3)` will return how many days you are away from Tuesday (where 3 in the formula above represents Tuesday as the start of the week). If you subtract the above (and add 1) from your delivery date then it should land on the previous Tuesday.

Comment: or just use 4 (Wednesday) and forget about adding the 1 to the formula.

Comment: Used the Wednesday and added an IF statement to use the current delivery date if it = 7.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IIF`, which is Access's unintuitive equivalent of `CASE` in normal SQL.  See for reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx

This code first checks if the date is a Tuesday and then if not counts back until it finds a Tuesday:

```
SELECT 
    IIF
    (format(yourdatevar, "dddd") = 'Tuesday'
        ,yourdatevar
        ,IIF(format(yourdatevar - 1, "dddd") = 'Tuesday'
        ,yourdatevar -1
        ,IIF(format(yourdatevar - 2, "dddd") = 'Tuesday'
        ,yourdatevar-2
        ,IIF(format(yourdatevar - 3, "dddd") = 'Tuesday'
        ,yourdatevar-3
        ,IIF(format(yourdatevar - 4, "dddd") = 'Tuesday'
        ,yourdatevar-4
        ,IIF(format(yourdatevar - 5, "dddd") = 'Tuesday'
        ,yourdatevar-5
        ,IIF(format(yourdatevar - 6, "dddd") = 'Tuesday'
        ,yourdatevar-6,null
        ))))))) as Delivery_date
FROM yourtbl
```